# Accessing a drive remotely

Tags: network-shares, network-drive

2 Computers:

1-> Laptop with Windows 8 running in hostel room (single partition c:)

2-> Desktop PC with Windows XP and/or Windows 7 running in a Lab

Both computers are connected via LAN and remote desktop access is working perfectly in either direction.

**Question:**

*I want to only access the C drive of my laptop from my Lab Desktop like a Network Drive and not involve remote desktop in between, but I am unable to do so as the hostel computers do no show up on the "Entire Windows Network" list* (maybe because they have a different subnet mask?). Although, I am able to add the Lab's NAS like a regular network drive.

Any help on how it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You mention that these two computer have different subnet masks, so are you aware that they are on different subnets? There may be a firewall preventing access to Windows shares between the subnets.

You can test the access by using the UNC path to the Windows 8 computer by browsing to the following file path in Explorer:

```
\\<computer_name\c$
```

Replacing `<computer_name>` with the hostname of the Windows 8 computer. You should be prompted for a username and password to access the hidden administrative share of the computer, for which you can use the credentials of a local administrator.

Comment: This is drawing a blank. If I enter the address directly in explorer - nothing happens (no loading, no waiting, no error - literally nothing). If I put it in the run box - I get an error that the network location could not be found. Same error if I try to add the share as a network drive directly. Also, yes, the computers are on different subnets.